# Install/run userscripts with Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, greasemonkey, userscripts

Greasemonkey in Chrome is seriously driving me bonkers. It looks like all the "documentation" I can find online pre-2009 tells you to do things one way, and everything since then has been another way.

1. What are the up-to-the-minute installation instructions for greasemonkey scripts? If something isn't working, how can I debug it? Specifically, I want to install [this script](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/24955) (which works fine in FFX). I've clicked the Install button, and it appears Chrome installed it as an extension, but the darn thing just doesn't work.
2. Possibly related to #1: I'm told that some userscripts are incompatible with Chrome. What specifically makes a script incompatible? If I'm comfortable with js programming, is it something I can fix on my own? I'll move this question to stackoverflow if it's inappropriate here...
3. If I go to somedomain.com, is there a way I can tell which userscripts are active for that page?

Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome has built in Greasemonkey script support. If you have it as a file on your computer, just drag it into the chrome window. It should popup a message prompting you to install the script.

Try replacing the last line with:

```
function main() {
    document.addEventListener("keypress", keyPressEvent, true);
}
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.appendChild(document.createTextNode('('+ main + ')();'));
document.body.appendChild(script);
```

Greasemonkey runs its scripts inside a sandbox. This should add the event listener outside of the sandbox. Might work better on Chrome.

Comment: Thanks for your help. This answer got me closer, but I still couldn't get it to work (the keyPressEvent function was inaccessible from the main function..still can't figure out why). I ended up installing the ReaderPlus chrome extension which has a mark-until-current-as-read feature. I'm (barely) resisting the urge to rant here...about that feature's absence from Google Reader in the first place.